# os.system or subprocess.call() not working in azure function

Tags: python-3.x, azure-function-app

I'm trying to run a .exe file with required dll's in same folder with os.system or subprocess.call(), which is woriking perfectly fine in local machine but after deployment even os.system('date') is resulting in 0. Is there anything I can do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

- use the check param of the subprocess.call to check the error code.
- check if your application needs vcredist to be installed.
- Used dependency walker to see what are dependencies of your application and make sure all the dependencies are available in your target environment.